# Элементы внутри div по центру и ширине

Tags: html, css

При попытке растянуть span по ширине div ничего не вышло. И text-align, который работает только для текста не помог, и inline-block тоже.

Как можно решить эту проблему?

```
<div class="iconBox">
    <span align="center" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span align="center" class="glyphicon glyphicon-hdd" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span align="center" class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span align="center" class="glyphicon glyphicon-saved" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>
```

```css
.iconBox {
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
}

.iconBox span {
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
#box {
  display: flex;
  height: 48px;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #F0F4F8;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
  <div class='item'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Еще как вариант

```css
.iconBox {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.glyphicon {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="iconBox" align='center'>
  <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true">123</div>
  <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-hdd" aria-hidden="true">456</div>
  <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks" aria-hidden="true">789</div>
  <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-saved" aria-hidden="true">012</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спустя столько времени `flex` сам использую и он предпочтительнее, чем `table` :)